# Windows service error

Tags: c#-4.0

I have written a windows service in C#.net. I was able to install it successfully. But when I go to Services and start the service, it gives me below error message 
" Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion"

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

When you write a service, you should not do any lengthy operation. You need to spawn a background thread and let the background thread to do the rest.

If `OnStart` method takes more than 30 seconds, windows assumes the service is not responding.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is because you made the mistake of not returning from the `OnStart` method of your service.  If you need to have ongoing work (which is basically every service) you should start a thread in your start method, and return as quickly as possible.